# Nodemon not reexecuting the chages that i have made locally

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a sample node function like hello world. After being executed using the command line `node myfirst.js`, hello world displayed in the browser. After installing the nodemon it re-execute on small changes, but some times it became stuck and failed to recompile on major changes which needs to restarted. Do i have to install any other npm packages?

Comment: 10 months later, you edit your question to ask a new question because you have problems with the answer  to the original question? Don't do that.

Comment: I have implemented the same to execute the program, now some one has vote down from asking me new question and banned . stack overflow ask me to improve current question .. this is one im actually facing. after integrating nodemon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use nodemon**

> Nodemon is a tool that helps develop node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.

Install it with `npm install nodemon -g`

Execute your app with:

```
nodemon myfirst.js
```

Instead of using `node myfirst.js`

The solution will refresh every time you save your edited code.

Comment: Indeed! Quick edit: You need to save your code for nodemon to refresh the output.

Comment: @Ardzii You are right, edited!

Comment: Please mark the answer as solution if valid, thanks!

Comment: nodemon is goo alternative, but I need to know whether there is native way to re-execute rather than using package

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I fully get what you need but you could try to use nodemon --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon
Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to know whether there is native way to re-execute rather than using package